# GCC: How to find out why a library is included in the executable

Tags: gcc, dynamic-linking, inkscape, libpng

This is the problem:

(On Linux Slackware64) I compiled Inkscape (0.92.3) and found that exporting to PNG doesn't work. An indication on the terminal tells me:

```
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.6.16 but running with 1.5.13
```

First reaction was to list the linked libraries using `ldd`. Indeed, both `libpng-1.6.16` and `libpng-1.5.13` are listed as necessary.

So, I suspected that some of the other libraries was requiring `libpng-1.5.13`. I made a small Python program which takes all the libraries (except the libpngs) and applies `ldd` to each of them. None of them listed `libpng15`. What now? I suspect that if any of the secondary libraries needed `libpng15`, it would be listed here, but, just in case I made the search recursive. No luck.

So it was, apparently, `inkscape` itself requesting the old version. A simple search in all files in the search tree only showed the string 'png15' in the viewer and actual inkscape executable.

There are probably older programs of mine still linked with png15, so I probably want to keep that version around.

Most, if not all references on the net mentioning this error (or similar) refer to programs with very old pnglibs (1.2.4x) trying to use a newer version, but here it's the other way around.

`libpng-config --version` reports `1.6.16`

Any suggestion how to identify the source of this problem? Particularly why inkscape included the old libpng?

Comment: Do you have both the dev and the normal packages (or whatever it is that one uses on slackware) installed for both versions?

Comment: Maybe try "lddtree" (from pax-utils) ?

Comment: @Moini: Yes, I have both. Slackware always installs the header files

Comment: @ewindes I suspect that script does something similar as the Python script I mentioned above. I'll try it out as soon as I can. Thanks!